# scala extend Stack doesn't work

Tags: scala, extends

This works

```
class Deck {
  var cards : Stack[Card] = new Stack[Card]
  for (card <- Card.possibleCards.keySet; suit <- Card.suits) {
    cards.push(new Card(card, suit))
  }
}
```

But this doesn't

```
class Deck[Card] extends Stack[Card] {
  for (card <- Card.possibleCards.keySet; suit <- Card.suits) {
    push(new Card(card, suit))
  }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error: class type required but Card found
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Works for me. What's your definition of "Stack"? However, it's not what you mean - Card  in yuor code is just a type parameter (e.g. it could be called anything  - T, for example). It will hide any other Card defined in your code. I think you mean `class Deck extends Stack[Card]`

Comment: import scala.collection.mutable.Stack

Comment: Still works for me. See my other comment, though, it's almost certainly not what you mean. Also, the definition of Card is needed for a complete reproducable example

Comment: Ah removing Card from Deck[Card] works :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was simply a syntax error, I needed to remove the class declaration Card from Deck.
Like so

```
class Deck extends Stack[Card] {
  for (card <- Card.possibleCards.keySet; suit <- Card.suits) {
    push(new Card(card, suit))
  }
}
```